# Handling variable assignment using callbacks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I've recently picked up Node and see that things don't always run sequentially. I'm pretty confused as I'm used to

```
1) Assignment
2) Print data
```

Current I'm running the below function and calling `var x = searchForProfessor("prof_name_here");`

I then call `console.log(x);` only to get undefined.

I've been reading about callbacks all over the web and I can't wrap my head around the idea and apply it to this code. Can someone give me some intuition into making the above possible with callbacks?

## My Function

```
var searchForProfessor = function searchForProfessor(teacher_name) {

  google.resultsPerPage = 10
  var nextCounter = 0

  google(teacher_name, function (err, res){

    for (var i = 0; i < res.links.length; ++i) {
      var link = res.links[i];
      if (!link.title.includes('Add') || !link.title.includes('RATINGS') || !link.title.includes("Hint")) {

        request(link, function(err, resp, body){

          if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) { //If no error is going to happen, then print the data
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);         //Grab the body of data from 'prof_link'
            var overall_rating = $('.breakdown-header .grade').text(); //Get the grade rating from the following classifications text

            if (overall_rating.substr(0,3)) {
              teacher_results.push(prof_name);
            } //End if
          } //End if
        }); //End request
      }//End if for comparisons ||
    } //End For
  }); //End google function
} //End searchForProfessor
```

Answer (score 2):

Because both your `google` and `request` functions are asynchronous data returned from those functions will not be immediately available, which is why `x`

```
var x = searchForProfessor("prof_name_here");
```

will always give you `undefined` when you try to log it.

To mitigate this problem you can pass in functions as parameters to other functions to return that data when it's available.

Here's a small mockup of what's happening with your code complete with how callbacks are used.

`async1` mimics a database connection - it returns an object using a key *after* 1 second by calling the function that's passed into it with the data as *its* first argument.

```
function async1(name, callback) {
  var obj = { tea001: { first: 'Dave', last: 'Batman' } };
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback(obj[name]);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Here we have your `searchForProfessor` function which accepts a name and a function. It calls `async1` with the name, passing in the callback as the second parameter. Note the `data` which is returned is the returned object data from `async1`. The callback that was passed into `searchForProfessor` is used to return that data to...

```
function searchForProfessor(teacher_name, callback) {
  async1(teacher_name, function (data) {
    callback(data);
  });
}
```

...this function call to `searchForProfessor` at which point you can log the data.

```
searchForProfessor('tea001', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

You can see in the demo that the returned data takes around a second to be logged to the console once the code is run.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9pbn7a2o/)